# How much are aircraft nose paintings restricted by regulations?

Tags: regulations

It's actually surprising to see these old paintings on aircraft noses:

[image]
<sup>WW2 nose art, [source](http://uproxx.com/ksk/sexy-friday-memorial-day-tribute-to-aircraft-nose-art-and-pinup-girls/)</sup>

How much were (and are) these paintings generally restricted or allowed by law, civil regulation and military rules in countries like US, Russia, India, Australia (if the jurisdiction matters for a general answer)?

Comment: "countries and societies with relatively low permissiveness for nudity:" - for example?

Comment: @Simon: That's not the point, I'm not starting another war... I'm talking about representation in public space.

Comment: :) I meant that your question is not clear.  You ask about "low permissiveness" then quote the UK where no-one bats an eyelid.  If you are simply asking about legal or civil restrictions, then perhaps the first sentence should be edited out since it is entirely subjective.

Comment: @Simon: I see, edited. I doubt this same picture would be allowed in a truck in the UK or in France, knowing how movie posters are fought...

Answer (score 4):

It used to be that nose art was pretty outlandish and sexually charged, and it remained largely unrestricted as this B-24 from WWII demonstrates.

[image]

With the current gender integrated units and women serving in combat squadrons, this kind of stuff is non longer acceptable.  Currently there's a rule, in at least the USAF, that nose art must be 'non-gender specific' i.e. you can't paint naked women on your airplane.

Comment: It wasn't allowed back in WWII either, but squadron commanders let them do it because it boosted morale during wartime.